# How Can I Get getc() to Return a Character Besides a Smiley Face?

Tags: c, file, getc

I am trying to write a simple 'cat' clone in C. I'm running Windows 7 and using the MinGW compiler. However, whenever I run the program, it returns the text file but with each character replaced with a '☺' character. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cat: can't open %s\n", argv[i]);
            continue;
        }

        while((c = getc(fp) != EOF))
        {
            putchar(c);
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since relational equal test (`!=`)  has greater precedence than assignment (`=`) you'll just store `1` in c at every iteration. Put otherwise, one of the brackets is in the wrong place.

```
while((c = getc(fp) != EOF))
                          ^
{
        putchar(c);
}
```

Right:

```
while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
{
        putchar(c);
}
```